# Creating a dynamic app in Android

Tags: android

I am currently looking to create an application in Android where a user can answer a questionnaire and that information is saved. The questionnaire will be in a sqlite database and can have different set on answers, and their can be several questionnaires the user can choose to fill. how do i go about firstly having the ability to create a dynamic questionnaire view for the user?

Comment: The questions do not need to be in random order. The questionnaire will be in a question database, and then one question can have different types of answers, so for example i would try show this in a spinner, or radio/checkbox. Then i need to save the answer into a table, there could be several different questionnaires and answers etc. i hope i am explaining it correctly

Answer (score 1):

You can add your questions in code?

Get your all questions from the database, and pick your questions, or just query them with a limit and an `order by rand()`

Then instead of hardcoding the questions in xml, you'll add them to your views with `.setText()`

Comment: As i am very new to android, are you able to provide code examples

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch questions from random rowids and present them... So, each time u execute, you will be fetching random questions from SQLite database and hence different questionnaire...

Comment: i don't need them to be random, and its the way i can get them out of the database, and then show them within one activity, and be able to handle the answers etc is what i am having difficulty with

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take to approaches:

1 - create a web-based view. You must read the questionnaire and generate the html, then present it in a `WebView`.

2 - generate a xml layout and inflate it. With "inflate" i'm referring to use the object [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) with some of inflate calls that accept an `XmlPullParser`, it's must generate a view exactly identical to a view defined in the IDE. I never test it so please let my know if it's works.

Comment: As i am very new to android, are you able to provide code examples